# Поиск и фильтрация в выпадающем списке

Tags: javafx

Пишу десктоп приложение, подскажите, пожалуйста, компонент для поиска в выпадающем списке. Т.е. есть инпут поле, по клику на которое ниже появляется выпадающий список с вариантами выбора. При вводе текста в этот инпут список автоматический фильтруется.

Answer (score 2):

Используем ComboBox. Включаем возможность набирать в нем текст:

```
comboBoxCountry.setEditable(true);
```

Создаем класс-слушатель (взято с забугорных сайтов и немного подпилено):

```
public class AutoCompleteComboBoxListener<T> implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

private ComboBox<T> comboBox;
private ObservableList<T> data;
private boolean moveCaretToPos = false;
private int caretPos;

public AutoCompleteComboBoxListener(final ComboBox<T> comboBox) {
    this.comboBox = comboBox;
    data = comboBox.getItems();

    this.comboBox.setEditable(true);
    this.comboBox.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            comboBox.hide();
        }
    });
    this.comboBox.setOnKeyReleased(AutoCompleteComboBoxListener.this);
}

@Override
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

    if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
        caretPos = -1;
        moveCaret(comboBox.getEditor().getText().length());
        return;
    } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
        if(!comboBox.isShowing()) {
            comboBox.show();
        }
        caretPos = -1;
        moveCaret(comboBox.getEditor().getText().length());
        return;
    } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
        moveCaretToPos = true;
        caretPos = comboBox.getEditor().getCaretPosition();
    } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DELETE) {
        moveCaretToPos = true;
        caretPos = comboBox.getEditor().getCaretPosition();
    }

    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT || event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT
            || event.isControlDown() || event.getCode() == KeyCode.HOME
            || event.getCode() == KeyCode.END || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
        return;
    }

    ObservableList<T> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        if(data.get(i).toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(
            //AutoCompleteComboBoxListener.this.comboBox.getEditor().getText().toLowerCase().trim())) {
            comboBox.getEditor().getText().toLowerCase().trim())) {
            list.add(data.get(i));
        }
    }
    String t = comboBox.getEditor().getText();

    comboBox.setItems(list);
    //comboBox.getEditor().setText(t);
    if(!moveCaretToPos) {
        caretPos = -1;
    }
    moveCaret(t.length());
    if(!list.isEmpty()) {
        comboBox.show();
    }
}

private void moveCaret(int textLength) {
    if(caretPos == -1) {
        comboBox.getEditor().positionCaret(textLength);
    } else {
        comboBox.getEditor().positionCaret(caretPos);
    }
    moveCaretToPos = false;
}

public static<T> T getComboBoxValue(ComboBox<T> comboBox){
    if (comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() < 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return comboBox.getItems().get(comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    }
}
}
```

Вешаем этот слушатель на ComboBox:

```
new AutoCompleteComboBoxListener<>(comboBoxCountry);
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К сожалению, работает это весьма убого (в чем можно убедиться, поигравшись с полученным компонентом), но вполне сносно. Как бы, вот только, его довести до ума?

P.S. Тема очень интересная и компонент, обладающий данной функциональностью крайне необходим.